# R: Get correct week number from date (beginning/end of year)

Tags: r

I struggle with getting my code correct. From my dataset I want to assign 'year+week' to all the dates but have not succeeded. The output I get is displayed below:

| referenceTime | Week |
| --- | --- |
| 31-12-2020 | 2020 - W53 |
| ... | ... |
| 01-01-2017 | 2017 - W52 |

01-01-2017 is in week 52 in 2016, and not 2017. It looks like a lot of other users also have difficulties with R not registrering beginning and ending of years, so the weeks get wrong. I have looked at other responses on StackOverflow but have not succeeded to find something that works for my code. The code I have now is this:

`data$Week <- format(df2$referenceTime, format="%Y-W%V")`

I am open for other suggestions, I see that some also use the `lubridate` package.

Hope someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: From `?strptime`: *‘%V’ Week of the year as decimal number (01-53) as defined in ISO           8601.  If the week (starting on Monday) containing 1 January has four or more days in the new year, then it is considered week 1.  Otherwise, it is the last week of the previous year, and the next week is week 1.  (Accepted but ignored on input.)*

Comment: Maybe you want `%W` instead of `%V` ?

Comment: You may want to use `%U`. See `?strptime` for details.

Comment: You could use package lubridate and then `paste0(isoyear(df2$referenceTime), "-" ,isoweek(df2$referenceTime))`. In the last case this will be 2016-52. This compares to using oracle's iyyy-iw formatting.

Comment: Thank you @phiver, this worked for my issue! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%G` *The week-based year* instead of `%Y`:

```
format(x, format="%G-%V")
#[1] "2020-53" "2016-52"
```

Or use `%U` instead of `%V`:

```
format(x, format="%Y-%U")
#[1] "2020-52" "2017-01"
```

Data:

```
x <- as.Date(c("2020-12-31", "2017-01-01"))
```